# How to combine toggle functions in one function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a toggle functions for show/hide images. But I have now two functions. And they do almost the same thing.

So my question is, how to combine them to one function?

So I have the template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!isShowWifi">
    <mgl-image id="wifi" url="./assets/radar.png" (loaded)="imageLoaded = true">
    </mgl-image>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="!isShowCamera">
    <mgl-image
      id="camera"
      url="./assets/noun_Camera.png"
      (loaded)="imageLoaded = true"
    >
    </mgl-image>
  </div>
```

and the buttons:

```
<div class="menu">
  <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" (click)="this.toggleDisplayDivIfCamera()">camera</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" (click)="this.toggleDisplayDivIfWifi()">wifi</mat-button-toggle>
</div>
```

and ts script:

```
 isShowCamera = false;
  isShowWifi = false;

  toggleDisplayDivIfWifi() {
    this.isShowWifi = !this.isShowWifi;
  }

  toggleDisplayDivIfCamera() {
    this.isShowCamera = !this.isShowCamera;
  }
```

So how can I write this in one function?

Thank you

Comment: You can create a function verifing the innerHtml of element with a condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a parametric variable name to toggle :

```
<mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" (click)="toggle('isShowWifi')">camera</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" (click)="toggle('isShowCamera')">wifi</mat-button-toggle>
```

TS:

```
toggle(what:string) {
    this[what] = !this[what];
}
```

Note : you don't call a method with `this.` from the template. Call `toggle()` directly.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cvnihd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `this[flag] != this[flag]` --> `this[flag] = !this[flag]`